# Equal string comparisons are failing

Tags: php

After hours of debugging, I have finally determine that for some reason on a particular web-server running my small script, two equal strings are apparently being interpreted as not equal to each other.

It makes absolutely no sense to me as I have tried comparing using "==" and "strcmp". While this code block works perfectly on my hosting, the person who is running my script continues to have it fail.

The results of the logging is...

DATA BEFORE EXPLODE: result=success;

DATA AFTER EXPLODE: result=success

NO

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $GLOBALS["api_url"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data1_log = "DATA BEFORE EXPLODE: " . $data;
log_activity($data1_log);

$data = explode(";",$data);

$data2_log = "DATA AFTER EXPLODE: " . $data[0];
log_activity($data2_log);

if (strcmp($data[0], "result=success") == 0)
{
    log_activity("YES");
}
else
{
    log_activity("NO");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a regex match, instead of split and compare? Also, it might be worth doing a `trim()` before compare.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense why comparing them with both "==" and "strcmp" fails on a particular web-server though does it?

Comment: Agreed. You could do an `md5()` of both strings and check if they are indeed equal on that server (in case there are unprintable characters etc)

Comment: did you try echoing out `$data[0]`?

Comment: +1 from trim() and md5()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [trim()](https://www.php.net/trim) (note the second parameter, which accepts other chracters like ";" in your case) and `strtolower()` or `strtoupper()` on both strings just before comparision.

Also, if you have the option to change the API response, try implementing a JSON response instead of returning a plain string. It will be less memory intensive and more maintainable.

Comment: I don't know, so i 've up your answer to zero :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using trim in your trim($data[0]); and compare it.